# Why fs.readFileSync returns nothing inside a promise on serveside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, promise

I found this ["Rendering PDFs with React components"](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/rendering-pdfs-with-react-components) tutorial on themeteorchef about creating PDF files on Meteor serverside and then sending them back to client. I had no really need for PDF files, but docx files instead and thought that maybe I could follow similar approach when creating docx files with **officegen**

I created very similar server side module that generates a docx file from inputs on clientside and then tries to transform them into base64 string that is then supposed to be sent to the client. However, the base64 string is never created.

Here's the module:

```js
let myModule;

const getBase64String = (loc) => {
  try {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(loc);
    return new Buffer(file).toString('base64');
  } catch (exception) {
    myModule.reject(exception);
  }
}

const generateBase64Docx = (path, fileName) => {
  try {
    myModule.resolve({fileName, base64: getBase64String(path+fileName)});
    fs.unlink(loc);
  } catch (exception) {
    myModule.reject(exception);
  }

}

const formatComponentAsDocx = (props, fileName) => {
  try {
    var docxFile = officegen({
      'type': 'docx',
      'orientation': 'portrait',
      'title': props.title,
    });

    var pObj = docxFile.createP();
    pObj.addText(props.body);

    var path = './';
    output = fs.createWriteStream(path+fileName);

    docxFile.generate(output);
    return path;

  } catch (exception) {
    myModule.reject(exception);
  }

}

const handler = ({props, fileName}, promise) => {
  myModule = promise;
  const path = formatComponentAsDocx(props, fileName);
  if (path) {
    generateBase64Docx(path, fileName);
  }
}

export const generateComponentAsDocx = (options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return handler(options, { resolve, reject });
  });
};
```

The problem here is the ***fs.readFileSync*** part. It always returns empty buffer and that's why the file is never transformed into base64 string and also never sent back to client. Why's that? The file itself is always created on the server and can always be found.

If I change the `const file = fs.readFileSync(loc);` part to for example this

```
fs.readFile(loc, (err, data) => {
 if(err) myModule.reject(err);
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

I can see some data in *data*, but not enough for the whole file.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something?

Comment: I encountered this problem when deleting files from Google Cloud and trying to render that reactively to client. Files get deleted correctly, but their handles aren't rendered away reactively. They render away only after refresh. So the root problem in these two cases is the same.

Comment: I was going to suggest a shot in the dark about whether the `fs.unlink(loc);` could be kicking-in at the wrong time, but then realised `loc` isn't defined at that point... Next: is `formatComponentAsDocx()` a synchronous call? I would have guessed not, but if it _isn't_, won't you be calling `generateBase64Docx()` to write its output too soon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the file generated by `officegen` is complete before you try to get the base64 out of it. That's the minimal change you need to make. I don't recommend waiting on the `finalize` event generated by `officegen` as this event is [buggy](https://github.com/Ziv-Barber/officegen/issues/26). I recommend waiting on the `finish` event of the output stream. However, there are **additional issues** with the code you show:

1. Since you have code to unlink the file immediately after you use it, then I infer you do not need a file. So you can just create the data in memory and get a `base64` string from that.
2. The whole rigmarole with `myModule` is awful awful design. If one of my colleagues presented such code, strong words would be exchanged. Yes, it is **that** bad. It is much better to convert the entire code base to work with promises.

The whole module can be reduced to the following. I've done a modicum of testing on this code but I don't claim that it deals with every eventuality.

```
import * as stream from "stream";
import officegen from "officegen";

function formatComponentAsDocx(props) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // There's no need to wrap this in try...catch only to call reject. If any
    // exception is raised in this function, the promise is automatically
    // rejected.
    const docxFile = officegen({
      'type': 'docx',
      'orientation': 'portrait',
      'title': props.title,
    });

    const pObj = docxFile.createP();
    pObj.addText(props.body);

    // We record the output in our own buffer instead of writing to disk,
    // and reading later.
    let buf = Buffer.alloc(0);
    const output = new stream.Writable({
      write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        buf = Buffer.concat([buf, chunk]);
        callback();
      },
    });

    docxFile.generate(output, {
      // Do propagate errors from officegen.
      error: reject,
    });

    // We don't use the "finalize" event that docxFile.generate would emit
    // because it is buggy. Instead, we wait for the output stream to emit
    // the "finish" event.
    output.on('finish', () => {
      resolve(buf);
    });
  });
}

export function generateComponentAsDocx({ props }) {
  return formatComponentAsDocx(props).then((data) => {
    return { base64: data.toString("base64") };
  });
};
```

Comment: Both these answers, this and answer from Styx, were good and guided me to right direction and actually fixed the problem. However, I'll mark this as the right answer as this is more elaborate and also tells me why I should rather use 'finish' than 'finalize'. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `docxFile.generate(output);` is *not synchronous*. Thus, while your local path exists (it was created by `fs.createWriteStream()` call), it is empty and your *synchronous* `fs.readFileSync` is catching just that, empty file.

You should subscribe to `docxFile`'s `finalize` event to catch file generation end:

```js
docxFile.on('finalize, function (writtenBytes) {
  // do you work with generated file here
});
```

Thus, rewriting your code:

```js
const handler = ({props, fileName}, promise) => {
  myModule = promise;
  formatComponentAsDocx(props, fileName);
}

const formatComponentAsDocx = (props, fileName) => {
  try {
    var docxFile = officegen({
      'type': 'docx',
      'orientation': 'portrait',
      'title': props.title,
    });

    var pObj = docxFile.createP();
    pObj.addText(props.body);

    var path = './';
    output = fs.createWriteStream(path+fileName);

    docxFile.on('error', function (err) {
      myModule.reject(err);
    });

    docxFile.on('finalize', function () {
      generateBase64Docx(path, fileName);
    });

    docxFile.generate(output);

  } catch (exception) {
    myModule.reject(exception);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

readFileSync is synchronous, so it doesn't deal in promises.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options

```
Synchronous version of fs.readFile. Returns the contents of the file.
```

You probably want to use fs.readFile.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback

```
    The callback is passed two arguments (err, data), where data is the contents of the file.

    If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I created a similar module as in tutorial that creates PDF files and there the fs.readFileSync returns the file in a buffer.

Comment: Maybe, can't see where that code is getting called from, but you mentioned promises in your question, and since it's synchronous that stuck out to me.   Are you trying to write the file and retrieve it when it's done writing?  if that's the case the write method should be async.  out of ideas for now.  good luck

Comment: The *generateComponentAsDocx* is called on client side from meteor server methods with basic Meteor.call(...). There only the props is passed to the module as it's the only external data it needs in this solution.